# jQuery fix click memorising

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".fsb").on("click", function () {
    if ($('.fsb').hasClass('fsbc')) {
        $('#sfo p').fadeIn(500);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#sfo p').fadeOut(500);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $('#sfof p').fadeIn(500);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#sfof p').fadeOut(500);
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

After clicking many times on the button(fast), it will repeat hiding and unhiding that much times. I want to disable that but have no ideas.(sorry, I'm new to this).

Comment: Take a look at clearTimeout() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: have a look at this: https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Instead of using timers consider using the callback feature of jQuery animation functions, eg `.fadeIn(duration, callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. jQuery allows to use [`.fadeIn()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`.fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) in chain without `setTimeout()`.
2. To remove all queued animation place [`.stop(true)`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) before them.
3. Inside the event handler, you can use `$(this)` to work on the clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fsb").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('fsbc')) {
      $('#sfo p').stop(true).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
    } else {
      $('#sfof p').stop(true).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-p p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="fsb fsbc">Click SFO</button>
<button class="fsb">Click SFOF</button>
<div id="sfo" class="hide-p">
  <p>SFO</p>
</div>
<div id="sfof" class="hide-p">
  <p>SFOF</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```